# Why are lambda updates "in progress" and "being created" instead of "successful"?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recall that previous updates of my AWS lambda functions responded with clear messages of success. But it seems recently the response changed to “in progress” and “being created”.

I don’t see a clear indication in the [AWS Documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html) that a change in syntax or functionality has occurred. Perhaps I’m misremembering?

Based on my functions output when invoked, they do successfully receive my updates. But still I wonder, why do I not see any mention of success in this output, and does it matter at all? AWS CLI version 2.2.16. Thank you.

```
aws lambda update-function-code \
    --zip-file fileb://MyProjectName.zip \
    --cli-connect-timeout 150 \
    --function-name myfunctionname

{
    "FunctionName": "myfunctionname",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:myfunctionname",
    "Runtime": "nodejs14.x",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myrolename",
    "Handler": "index.handler",
    "CodeSize": 7000273,
    "Description": "",
    "Timeout": 6,
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "LastModified": "2021-11-23T17:50:04.000+0000",
    "CodeSha256": "QW+wertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm=",
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "Environment": {
        "Variables": {
            "CONSUMER_SECRET": "qwertyuiopasdfghjkl",
            "CONSUMER_KEY": "qwertyuiopasdfghjkl",
            "ACCESS_TOKEN": "qwertyuiop-asdfghjkl",
            "WORK": "myfunctionname",
            "NODE_ENV": "production",
            "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET": "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKL"
        }
    },
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "RevisionId": "1234567890-1234567890-1234567890",
    "State": "Active",
    "LastUpdateStatus": "InProgress",
    "LastUpdateStatusReason": "The function is being created.",
    "LastUpdateStatusReasonCode": "Creating"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[AWS recently announced that they decided to expand lambda states to all functions.](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/coming-soon-expansion-of-aws-lambda-states-to-all-functions/) There are two options for you. (Option2 is recommended.)

Option 1. If you don't want to apply new updates for your lambda, simply add `aws:states:opt-out` configuration to your function’s Description.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Option 2. Execute the following command right after running `aws lambda update-function-code` so that you can wait till the state of your lambda becomes 'Successful'

```
aws lambda wait function-updated --function-name $FUNC_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

From the AWS docs, these are the [function states while updating](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/functions-states.html):

> Lambda provides additional context for functions undergoing updates
> with the `LastUpdateStatus` attribute, which can have the following
> statuses:
>
> `InProgress` – An update is happening on an existing function. While a
> function update is in progress, invocations go to the function’s
> previous code and configuration.
>
> `Successful` – The update has completed. Once Lambda finishes the
> update, this stays set until a further update.
>
> `Failed` – The function update has failed. Lambda aborts the update
> and the function’s previous code and configuration remain available.

Creating a Lamdba function takes a few seconds/minutes. You probably pushed an update to your Lamdba code, while the function was still creating.

I'm not aware of any recent changes to the API.

Comment: To clarify, I’m pushing updates to lambda functions that I created months ago, and that have been executing at a fixed rate (approximately once every 90 minutes) via CloudWatch event rules.